# I got an empty list when solving two equation

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I tried to solve two simple equations but I got nothing.

```
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols('x y')
eq1=Function('eq1')
eq2=Function('eq2')

eq1 = Eq(x + y , 1)        # x + y   = 1
eq2 = Eq(x + y ,3)         # x + y  = 3
ans = solve([eq1, eq2] , [x, y])
print(ans)
```

I got

```
[]
```

Comment: What were you expecting? What *are* the values of x and y such that their sum is both 1 *and* 3?

Comment: `x+y=1` and `x+y=3` how can you even solve these equations? In simple terms your equations are like `1+1=2` and `1+1=3` makes no sense.

Comment: easy man :) ,, iam just beginner

Comment: whouid you please help me in my qestion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910262/keyerror-while-perfoming-solve-of-two-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set everything up ok. The empty list is the way that `solve` tells you that it could not find a solution for `x` and `y` that satisfied the equations. And, indeed, there are no values which, when added, will give two different results (as others have noted).